# How to modelize that a machine should stay off during 5 consecutive hours at least by a linear constraint?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

I need to model the constraint that "the machine can be turned off if needed but once it has been turned off, it should stay off during at least 5 hours".

I have created a variable $c_{i}$ s.t. $c_{i}=1$ iff the machine is stopped at time $i+1$ (I know it could seem odd but it's like this) and $e_{i}$ s.t. $e_{i}=1$ if the machine is restarted at time $i+1$. Moreover, $a_{i}=1$ if the machine produces at time $i$. (I have established the correct constraints between $a_{i}$ and  $c_{i}$ and $e_{i}$).

However, I don't manage to express in term of linear programming constraints the fact that "the machine can be turned off if needed but once it has been turned off, it should stay off during at least 5 hours"

EDIT: so far, the constraints (among others) look like :

$e_{i}\geq a_{i+1}-a_{i}$
$e_{i} \leq a_{i+1}$
$e_{i} \leq 1-a_i$

$c_{i}\geq a_{i}-a_{i+1}$
$e_{i} \leq a_{i}$
$e_{i} \leq 1-a_{i+1}$

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you are doing integer programming, not linear programming. In linear programming, for example, if $a_0=0,$ $a_1=0.5,$ and $a_2=1,$ then $e_0=e_1=0.5,$ so depending on how you interpret $e_i=0.5$ (namely, is $0.5$ "true" or "false"?), the machine is either started twice in a row without stopping or goes from off ($0$) to on ($1$) in two hours without being started. If you restrict the input values to integers, however, your formulas work. The restriction to integers is what distinguishes integer programming from linear programming.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, in my code I restricted the variables to be integers. I have an idea about how to fix my problem, I test it and then come back :-)

Comment: @DavidK Could you please take a look at my answer and feedback it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found on my own the way to fix that problem :

By calling $q_i$ the quantity produced by the machine at time $i$ and $Q$ the overall quantity to be produced :

$\sum_{k=i+1}^{i+5} q_k \leq Q \cdot (1-c_i) $

By this way, the machine can not produce anything during the 5 following periods after the machine was turned off.

I guess that we can replace $q_k$ by $a_k$ and therefore $Q$ by 5 in this case.

I hope it will help other people ;-)

Comment: I believe this works. It seems to make good use of the variables you have already defined. (I assume you already have constraints $a_i\geq 0$ for all $i$; if not, I think you need them here.) Since $c_i = 1 \implies a_{i+1}=0,$ you can omit $a_{i+1}$ from the sum, so you just need $a_{i+2}+a_{i+3}+a_{i+4}+a_{i+5}\leq 4(1-c_i).$

Comment: You're right. Indeed I had already fixed $a_i \geq 0$ (inside the code, this is done by fixing the bounds). I tested it on a quite simple example and it seems that it worked well... :-). Thanks anyway !

Comment: I think it would be OK for you to accept this answer now. It's a correct answer, and as you say, it could be helpful to other people as well.

Comment: @DavidK Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

By "stopped at time $i+1$" I suppose you mean that $a_i = 1$ and
$a_{i+1} = 0,$ that is, the machine was running at time $i$ but is no longer
running at time $i+1.$
Similarly, I suppose $e_i$ means $a_i = 0$ and $a_{i+1} = 1.$

I also suppose that the unit of time is one hour, that is,
time $i+1$ is one hour later than time $i,$
and that changes in status (such as the machine turning on or off)
occur only at the top of the hour, for example at 10 am or 2 pm
but never at 10:30 am.

So if the machine stops at time $i+1,$ you know it is off for at least an
hour, and you just need to make sure it doesn't get restarted at any of
the next four possible times, which you can explicitly list.
Alternatively, you know that if $c_i$ and $e_j$ are true,
there are certain conditions that the numbers $i$ and $j$ must satisfy.

Comment: Your asumptions are indeed right but can you precise more clearly what is the solution to my problem, please ? Actually, the way it should be formulated must be linear programming constraints (it's a constraint of a linear optimization problem)

Comment: You have, among other constraints, $c_i = 1 \implies e_{i+1} = 0$ for all $i.$ I'm not sure how you want this expressed. Perhaps it would help to see how you expressed the constraints you already were able to do.

Comment: I have edited my question